# Bug, Bone Constraints are Greyed Out

Tags: animation, rigging, bones

I am learning about bone constraints but have found myself unable to even select them. I started a new file to undo anything that might have contributed to the problem but I am still experiencing this same issue. In the screenshot attached, it is identical to the start up file except I've simply added a single bone. When I navigate to the bone constraints tab and attempt to add one, all of the constraints are greyed out and are unable to be used. Please help.[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cpPHt.jpg)

Comment: To extend the answer, you have not added a single bone, you have added a single *armature*. You add bones to the armature in edit mode and add constraints to the bones in pose mode.

Answer (score 2):

You need to be in *Pose* mode to have access to the constraints.